# How to send email with not necessary Multiple Attachments from html form in PHP

Tags: php, email, attachment, photo

I have get value from html form and send via email with multiple attachments. Attachments are not necessary.

I have got some piece of code to send multiple attachments through mail function in php But my mail sending fails and i dont know why. My attachments are not necessary. This is my code:

```
<?php
function multi_attach_mail($to, $subject, $message, $senderMail, $senderName, $files){
    $from = $senderName." <".$senderMail.">";
    $headers = "Siuntėjęs: $from";

    // boundary
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    // headers for attachment
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    // multipart boundary
    $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";

    // preparing attachments
    if(count($files) > 0){
        for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
            if(is_file($files[$i])){
                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                $fp =    @fopen($files[$i],"rb");
                $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($files[$i]));

                @fclose($fp);
                $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"\n" .
                "Content-Description: ".basename($files[$i])."\n" .
                "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"; size=".filesize($files[$i]).";\n" .
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            }
        }
    }

    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
    $returnpath = "-f" . $senderMail;

    //send email
    $mail = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);

    //function return true, if email sent, otherwise return fasle
    if($mail){ return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }

}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'
    && !empty($_POST['namecontact'])
    && !empty($_POST['namecarinfo']) ) {

      $contacts = array(
        //"autoperka.info@gmail.com",
        //"automobiliukas24@gmail.com",
      //  "ruslanneviadomskij@gmail.com",
          "gabriele.giniot@gmail.com"
      );

    foreach($contacts as $contact) {

      $to = $contact; // this is your Email address
      $from = $_POST['namecontact']; // this is the sender's Email address
      $carinformation = $_POST['namecarinfo'];
      $coment = $_POST['namecoment'];
      $subject = $from . " SupirkimasPlius.lt";
      $from_name = $_POST['namecontact'];

      //$headers = "Siuntėjas:" . $from;



//attachment files path array
$file_tmp_name  = $_FILES['namephoto']['tmp_name'];
$fileName       = $_FILES['namephoto']['name'];
$fileType       = $_FILES['namephoto']['type'];
$files = $fileType;
// Message
$html_content = '<br>
<h3>Automobilio pasiūlymas:</h3>
<br>Marke: '.$carinformation.'
<br>Kontaktai: '.$from.'
<br>Komentaras: '.$coment.
'<br>Nuotraukų kiekis'.count($files);



//call multi_attach_mail() function and pass the required arguments
$send_email = multi_attach_mail($to,$subject,$html_content,$from,$from_name,$files);

//print message after email sent
}
  $myfile = fopen("success.php", "r") or die(fopen("index.php", "r"));
  echo fread($myfile,filesize("success.php"));
  fclose($myfile);
  //mail('gabriele.giniot@gmail.com',$subject,$message,$headers);
  //mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender


  } else {
    $myfile = fopen("failed.php", "r") or die(fopen("index.php", "r"));
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("failed.php"));
    fclose($myfile);
  }
?>
```

please help me :)

Comment: At first glance, all I see is that you separate the mail headers with `\n` when it should be `\r\n`. I'm also not sure how your mail server will handle a `Siuntėjęs` header, I'm pretty sure it should be plain old ASCII. Usually, the `From` header is localised by the user's mail program and not in the headers. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Puh, properly encoding an email message is a tough job! Specification and libraries exists publicly (there are even some binary extensions for PHP for that), but the one function you use there just by the little number of lines it has I'm pretty sure is unfitting for a MIME encoded email message. I guess it was just intended for some rudimentary example to show that things do some work sometimes but are not a fit for a particular purpose. But why a multi-part message anyway? Why don't you send a plain text message?